# Staticfiles not a registered tag and staticfiles not loading

Tags: python, django

My staticfiles will not load no matter what and I'm at the point where I've looked through stackoverflow and read documentation for five hours so I need help.

Here's my URL for urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('notebook.urls'))
]
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

Meanwhile this is my settings for my project and I'm egregiously been trying to figure out why my staticfiles have not loaded. I'm not running this in a virtualenv so those related issues  have been addressed I've looked over the Django documentation to try and find where in my setting the reason the staticfiles are not loading and I after hours of that and staackoverflow not a single answer has availed.

This is my settings file for the project

```
    """
Django settings for onesky project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# Static file directory
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")
# Static files for multiple directories
STATICFILES_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
# Media file directory
MEDIA_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'q*6q$)mqhr**pwaj4m!8km&2i7s2ewu+lg%7p$*pm6+8!l8cwf'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'rest_framework',
    'notebook',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'onesky.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                'django.template.context_processors.media',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'onesky.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = STATICFILES_DIR

# Media Root
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_DIR
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
```

Just for completeness here is also wgsi.py file

```
"""
WSGI config for onesky project.

It exposes the WSGI callable as a module-level variable named ``application``.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/
"""

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "onesky.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Here's my template code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
{% load staticfiles %}

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>OneSky</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static "css/normalize.css" %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static'css/home.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static '/css/notebook.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static 'css/skeleton.css' %}">
</head>
<body>
<div class="row" style="padding-top: 1%;">
    <div class="nav">
        <div class="three columns">
            <div class="logo">OneSky</div>
        </div>
        <!--
           @TODO:Change to class based styling
        -->
        <div class="seven columns" style="height: 100%">
            <div class="spacer"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="one column">
            <img src="{% load static 'img/settings-cog.png' %}" class="icon">
        </div>
        <div class="one column">
            <img src="img/account.png" class="icon">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="data-container">
<div class="row">

        <div class="three columns" style="overflow: hidden">
            <div class="scroll-container">
            <div class="note-container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="eight columns">
                    <h2 class="note header"> Notebook </h2>
                </div>
                <div class="two columns">
                    <img src="img/add-button.png" class="icon">

                </div>
                <div class="two columns">
                    <img src="img/list-button.png" class="icon">
                </div>
            </div>
                <div id="content" class="hiddenscrollbars">
                <hr>
                    {% for post in posts %}

                            <div class="row">
                    <div class="note-title">
                        <h4> {{ post.title }}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                    {% endfor %}

            </div>

                </div>

        </div>
            </div>
    </div>


<div class="eight columns">
    <div class="row">
        <h3 class="selected-note-title">Select Something</h3> <span><button class="submit" title="submit">Save</button></span>
    </div>
    <div class="scrolling-container">
        <div class="editor-container">
        </div>

    </div>
</div>

</div>
</div>








</body>
<!-- Include the Quill library -->
<script src="js/quill.js"></script>
<!-- Initialize Quill editor -->
<script src="js/notebook.js"></script>


</html>
```

Thank you in advance for assistance

Comment: How did you try to access it, and what error do you get when you try to access it?

Comment: ''img'' is not a registered tag library. Must be one of:
admin_list
admin_modify
admin_static
admin_urls
cache
i18n
l10n
log
rest_framework
static
staticfiles
tz   @almostabeginner

Comment: Can you please update your question and add relevant template code also, thanks.

Comment: Added it @almostabeginner

Comment: I think it might be related to  `<img src="{% load static 'img/settings-cog.png' %}" class="icon">`; remove `load` from the tag. Django thinks you're loading a custom tag. I might be wrong, but give it a try and let me know if it works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `static` to get the url of static files, instead you're using `load static`, which confuses Django to think you're loading a custom tag.

The only instance where you need to use `load` is:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
```

Change these:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static "css/normalize.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static'css/home.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static '/css/notebook.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% load static 'css/skeleton.css' %}">
....
....
<img src="{% load static 'img/settings-cog.png' %}" class="icon">
```

To:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "css/normalize.css" %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static'css/home.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static '/css/notebook.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/skeleton.css' %}">
....
....
<img src="{% static 'img/settings-cog.png' %}" class="icon">
```

Comment: @travissmith glad i could help.

Answer (score 0):

At the starting of your hrml templates, you might have to use

{& load static %} not staticfiles

That's  why templatesytaxerror is raised.